# How to ensure that all the non-origin href links open in a new tab?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have a html content stored in backend, which may have certain anchor tags with href links, when rendering them I build a custom `NodeValidator` and then bind the value using a angular.dart decorator. Some of the href links points to outside my domain, I want to make sure that `target='_blank'` is added as attribute to such anchor tags so that browsers open the link in a new tab. Can this be taken care of by some `UriPolicy` or custom `NodeValidator`?